# Ubuntu 20.04 QCA 9377 driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 i was able to fix the RT ethernet drivers but the issue is with WiFi drivers
QCA9377 is WiFi chipset, When i try to install drivers i get error missing driver unable to locate drivers. When i update no driver is shown , Can you suggest how to install WiFi drivers.
Also the audio drivers is not working , so also touchpad drivers has issues,touchpad stops intermittently. Can you suggest drivers for all of these.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Ubuntu+20.04+QCA+9377+driver ?  (i.e.: https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:168c-0042-17aa-0901&page=1 )

Comment: I suspect that you are missing *linux-modules-extra*. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal comand: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I installed linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) and rebooted the device now all the drivers are seen in 20.04 , Thanks for suggesting this command.

Comment: Please convert your comment to an answer that you may accept and that I may upvote. Accepted answers help others find the correct solution when they have the same problem. Thanks for your follow-up.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the issue I installed `linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)` and rebooted the device now all the drivers are seen in 20.04.